# Javascript populate JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm struggling on how to make the following JSON array:

```
{
    "location": [
        [
            50.81040819,
            4.92792551
        ],
        [
            40.81040819,
            4.92792551
        ]
    ]
}
```

I pull the data from instagram where I get the following (with much more data):

```
"location": {
    "latitude": 50.81040819,
    "longitude": 4.92792551
}
```

But I need the coordinates grouped like the first example. Is there any way I can recreate this, basically without the key?

thx in advance

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: What's wrong with keeping the keys as given? Is it necessary to remove them? In my opinion, it would be best to keep them, as they add description.

Answer (score 2):

```
var your_data = {location: {longitude: 50, latitude: 40}}; 
var location_arr = [your_data[location][longitude], your_data[location][latitude]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your data an array of objects each with a location key?  If so, you can do the following:

```
formatted = {};    

formatted.location = myData.filter(function(object) {
       return object.location;
    }).map(function(object) {
       return [object.latitude, object.longitude];
    });
```

The filter function filters in all the objects that have a location (in case some don't have a location key).

The map function replaces each of your objects with an array consisting of a latitude and longitude.  The formatted object now looks like what you want.

For example:

```
[{location: {latitude: 50, longitude: 40}},
 {location: {latitude: 30, longitude: 20}},
 {something: {name: "someName"}}
]
```

becomes

```
{ 
    location: [
        [50, 40],
        [30, 20]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not having worked with instagram before, I'm unsure about how your input is ordered. I guess you get the `location` as part of an array in a JSON message.

I would probably use `Array.prototype.map` in the following way (or something similar):

```
// "input" is simply the input JSON string and "output" is the completed 
// JSON string after remapping the data:

var data = JSON.parse(input);
var output = JSON.stringify( remap(data) );

function remap(array) {
    return { "location" : array.map(function (current) {
        return [ current.location.latitude, current.location.longitude ];
        })
    };
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle using some mock data and the same idea:
http://jsfiddle.net/fLx1gshd/1/

Answer (score 0):

When you get external json there are some parsing that needs to be done but to show you how to get the exact format you need in a simple way is here: http://jsfiddle.net/37mgoybf/1/

I'm assuming your getting an array of objects and we can save it in a variable for now:

```
var i = [
        {
          "location": {
            "latitude": 50.81040819,
            "longitude": 4.92792551
          }
        },{
          "location": {
            "latitude": 40.81040819,
            "longitude": 4.92792551
          }
        }
     ];
```

Now we create a new object to store the formatted data

```
var p = {};
p.location = []; //create an empty location array
```

Then we can loop over i to get the formate

```
//Loop over the data and create an array of properties
//Push that array into the location array for final formate
for(var key in i){
var lat = i[key].location.latitude;
var long = i[key].location.longitude;
var arr = [];
arr.push(lat, long);
//arr[key] = long;
p.location.push(arr);
//console.log(i[key])
}
```

Now if we print p it would be

```
    {
    "location": [
        [
            50.81040819,
            4.92792551
        ],
        [
            40.81040819,
            4.92792551
        ]
    ]
   }
```

Hope this makes sense, there are other ways of doing it but above is an easy way. Objects and arrays are fun to work with but could get frustrating at times. Good luck!